# Accessing included class's protected constant in a ActiveSupport::Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, separation-of-concerns

What's the simplest way to access included class's protected constant in the ActiveSupport::Concern context?

Example classes:

```
module Printable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

private
    def print_constant
        puts MY_CONSTANT
    end
end

class Printer
    include Printable

    def print
        print_constant
    end

private
    MY_CONSTANT = 'Hello'.freeze
end
```

This solution produces an error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Printable::MY_CONSTANT
```

I'm aware of an alternative that seems to work:

```
puts self.class::MY_CONSTANT
```

But, it doesn't feel right. :-)

Any better suggestions?

Comment: Your question was my answer.  While I agree that it doesn't feel right, your question finally gave me a solution that at least worked.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, you should put `#print_constant` into an `included` block:

```
module Printable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    private

    def print_constant
      puts MY_CONSTANT
    end
  end
end
```

Now there are at least two ways of accessing the class constant `MY_CONSTANT`:

1. `#included` yields with a `base` parameter similar to Ruby's
   [`#included`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-included):

   ```
   module Printable
     extend ActiveSupport::Concern

     included do |base|
       private

       define_method :print_constant do
         puts base::MY_CONSTANT
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. Another method is going from `self.class`:

   ```
   module Printable
     extend ActiveSupport::Concern

     included do
       private

       def print_constant
         puts self.class::MY_CONSTANT
       end
     end
   end
   ```

[ActiveSupport Concern Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a constant of an including class from a concern isn't really a good idea.

A concern shouldn't have (too much) knowledge of the classes it's included in.

I would go for a common API in the concern and override when needed... like this:

```
module Printable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

private
    def print
      puts ""
    end
end

class Printer
    include Printable

    def print
        MY_CONSTANT
    end

private
    MY_CONSTANT = 'Hello'.freeze
end
```

Comment: You'll have a method hyperinflation on the order of (number of including classes) x (number of methods using the constant)  :)